# Web application references for a C# windows application developer

Tags: asp.net

I am used to working on C# .NET windows applications. I am interested in starting with web applications. Can you suggest some good ebooks or references for C# ASP.net to begin with for a guy like me who is comfortable with windows applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out the below:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms

By the way, you may have noticed a lot of discussion about ASP.Net MVC?

If not, check out this link for more information:

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Since WebForms has been intentionally designed to allow developers transition from a WinForm/Desktop paradigm easily you may find this option a little more familiar!

Answer (score 0):

I used this.

Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010, Fourth Edition
http://apress.com/book/view/1430225297

(actually I used a previous edition for ASP.NET 2, but the principle stands)

I still use it now for reference purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET: A Beginner's Guide by David Mercer](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0072195126/qid=1122214265/sr=1-1/ref=sr_1_1/104-1804612-3720739?v=glance&s=books)

I would start learning ASP.NET MVC anyway! ;)